# Statefulsets pods in Kiali Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, kiali

Can anybody help me here, I'm not able to see my statefulset application in Kiali Dashboard (application: elasticsearch and Other statefulset ) . i have installed istio using istioctl manifest apply (demo profile).  i am able to see all other workload like pods , servcice but not stateful set .

Not sure what i need to configure in the generated manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

The [kiali CR](https://github.com/kiali/kiali/blob/master/operator/deploy/kiali/kiali_cr.yaml#L568) by default excludes statefulset.

```
excluded_workloads:
    - "CronJob"
    - "DeploymentConfig"
    - "Job"
    - "ReplicationController"
    - "StatefulSet"
```

You need to remove  StatefulSet from exclusions by modifying the CR and applying it in your cluster. Check this [issue](https://github.com/kiali/kiali/issues/1903).

Comment: I'm not using Kiali Operator so I can not remove from excluded workloads. i'm using istioctl manifest to generate YAML file to install istio with all component in gke

Comment: you should have a ConfigMap named kiali in istio-system namespace. Edit that ConfigMap to exclude statefulset and restart kiali pod